# Merge Statement: Don't update blank field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge, case

I'm performing a MERGE statement from a temp table `t` into the main table `ts`, matching on an ID field. It contains the following:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
   SET ts.username = t.username, ts.password = t.password, ts.title = t.title, ts.firstname = t.firstname, ts.surname = t.surname, ts.email = t.email
```

If the username and password is blank in the temp table `t`, I don't want to update the main table `ts`. How can I do this?

EDIT: Seems like a `CASE` statement or using `COALESCE(NULLIF(t.username, ''), ts.username)` will work. Which is best?

Comment: Is it ok for you to do a dummy update? I.e. set ts.username = coalesce(t.username, ts.username), ...

Comment: @Frank Schmitt I never knew about the COALESCE function. If I use this with NULLIF I think that will do it!

Comment: What is the actual issue: Would you like to remove record from the update, because it will always update, even if you set it to the previous value.

Comment: Just don't want to overwrite an existing username/password with a blank value. Got this covered now thanks to Frank Schmitt and Chris Gessler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with blanks (i.e. empty string), then using a case statement

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
   SET case when t.username = '' then ts.username else t.username end
```

If you're dealing with null, then use isnull

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
   SET ts.username = isnull(t.username, ts.username),
```

If it can be either blank or null, you can deal with both in a case statement

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
   SET case when t.username = '' or t.username is null then ts.username else t.username end
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, this worked, however I decided to use `ISNULL(NULLIF(t.username, ''), ts.username)` instead as it's more compact to write than a case statement.